# How to get date in BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to get today date in Window `*.bat` file. After it I would like to get day, month and year. How can I do this?

I can't use PowerShell

Comment: Just tape [ echo %date% ] or [ echo %date% >> "test.txt" ] for save the date in a new text file

Comment: @MehdiBugnard Seems that it's not for user output but for working with it in another batch...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You get and format like this

```dos
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
set datestr=%month%_%day%_%year%
echo datestr is %datestr%
```

**Note: Above only works on US locale.** It assumes the output of `echo %date%` looks like this: `Thu 02/13/21`. If you have different Windows locale settings, you will need to modify the script based on your configuration.

Comment: This is dependent on the regional settings on the computer.  If it works then good, but it is not a robust method.

Comment: You should better add that your solution works with an English locale. Especially in my case date is the following `01.12.2015`, so this solution may have helped (which is great), but its value is limited. Make the limitation explicit, and I guess you'll possibly get some more upvotes.

Comment: @Wolf there are many different English locales with different date formats like AU, UK, US...

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, that's true. My point was to explicitly add its limitation to the solution shown :)

Answer (score 95):

This will give you `DD MM YYYY YY HH Min Sec` variables and works on any Windows machine from XP Pro and later.

```dos
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Comment: I'd never expect to find such a useful tool here: [WMIC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx#EDAA) -- thanks for the introduction :-)

Comment: When running manually on the commandline I had to remove the extra % from %%a : for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%a"   (but when putting it in a script you need the extra %)

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

`%date%` will give you the date.

`%time%` will give you the time.

The `date` and `time /t` commands may give you more detail.

Answer (score 11):

Locale-independent one liner to get any date format you like. I use it to generate archive names. Back quote (`) option is needed because PowerShell command line is using single quotes (').

```
:: Get date in 'yyyyMMdd_HHmm' format to use with file name.
FOR /f "usebackq" %%i IN (`PowerShell ^(Get-Date^).ToString^('yyyyMMdd_HHmm'^)`) DO SET DTime=%%i

:: Get yesterday date in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.
FOR /f "usebackq" %%i IN (`PowerShell ^(Get-Date^).AddDays^(-1^).ToString^('yyyy-MM-dd'^)`) DO SET DTime=%%i

:: Show file name with the date.
echo Archive.%DTime%.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

```
set datestr=%date%
set result=%datestr:/=-%
@echo %result%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the date in this format mmddyyyy saved into %today%, assuming your regional settings have you in the US locale.

```
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ("%date%") DO SET today=%%a%%b%%c
```

In my case I was looking to create a folder with todays date, like this...

mkdir C:\Users\LKrell\Documents\%today%