# Create a batch file that creates a directory with a name format: current month.If month will change it will create another directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can someone help me in creating a batch file that creates a parent directory with a name format: current month then continues to create sub directory name format: yyyy_mm_dd. If the month changes it will create another parent directory.

Comment: this should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131029/how-to-get-date-in-bat-file

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=batch+create+folder+with+today%27s+date+site%3Astackoverflow.com) just on site [SO]  gets you a whole bunch of hits.