# Double-pipe statement with two commands using the `&&` on a `for` loop (batch script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

Based on [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21912169/6003691) and comments from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/734598/6003691), I cannot understand how to **add a double-pipe `||` statement with two commands using the `&&` on a `for` loop**. Consider the following example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131662/6003691):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

If I try

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" || echo Error while getting datetime. >> %someoutputfile% && GOTO endthis
```

I get a `Unexpected &&` error. I tried adding parenthesis around the each command after the `||` but they too give `Unexpected )` similar errors.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Should I put the `||` commands before the `do set "dt=%%a"` or something?

Answer (score 1):

You may also use this approach:

```
(for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a") || rem

if errorlevel 1 echo Error while getting datetime. >> %someoutputfile% & GOTO endthis
```

This method is fully described below **Exit Code management** at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987886/778560).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
@ echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('WMIC OS Get LocalDateTime /value') do (
    set dt=%%a && (
        echo Local Data Time: "%dt%"
    ) || (
        echo Error while getting datetime.
        goto ERROR
    )
)

echo Exiting...
goto END

:ERROR
echo Terminating...

:END
```

Comment: Isn't this applying the checks for the error (i.e. the two commands after the `||`) only to the `set dt=%%a` command and not to the whole `for` loop?

Comment: @Karim: Yes. The syntax is for the command. The `for` loop doesn't have a separate syntax like this.